# cinnamon change name of workspaces by bash

Tags: command-line, workspaces, cinnamon, gsettings

I want to update the names of workspace by bash.

When I run:

```
$ gsettings get org.cinnamon.desktop.wm.preferences workspace-names
['0 - Main', 'Project name', 'second project', 'other']
```

So I try to update that value with:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.wm.preferences workspace-names "['0 - Main', 'rename', 'renamew', 'other']"
```

When I run the `get` afterwords it *does* return the updated value. But I don't see the labels when I switch workspaces or whatever.

Is this some kind of "array" format that I'm entering wrong?
Or should this be done in a complete different way?

I'm running cinnamon on Ubuntu, but this is probably a gsettings question mostly.

Answer (score 1):

I tried changing the names with your strategy and it worked (taking effect after logging out and back in).

I think your problem is not a failure to change the names, but that your workspace settings are set to not showing the labels when switching workspaces.

In cinnamon, try the following:

go to **Settings > Workspaces** and Enable workspace OSD.

Comment: That's a good point about logging out. OSD did not matter. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

gsettings still works in Linux Mint 19.1 but syntax changed a bit:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.wm.preferences workspace-names '@as ["Main","Surf","Mail","Edit"]'
```

Cinnamon restart required afterward!

I did not find any settings menu for this Workspace naming in a fresh installed Linux Mint 19.1.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! As the name says, this site is designated for Ubuntu. If this change is also related to it, you should specify the Ubuntu version. Linux Mint is _based on_ Ubuntu but not an official flavour. More information: [Are Linux Mint (and other unofficial derivatives of Ubuntu) questions on topic?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/684/are-linux-mint-and-other-unofficial-derivatives-of-ubuntu-questions-on-topic)